# Determining the complete URL but without the script name?

Tags: php

Basically I'm trying to determine the complete web-accessible URL of a certain script, but without the script name.

For example, I was thinking of something along these lines:

```
$fullURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo $fullURL;
```

So if the file was `http://example.com/path/to/file.php`, then that's what it would display: `http://example.com/path/to/file.php`. However, I want it to display `http://example.com/path/to/`

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`dirname`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function:

```
 $fullURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This will exclude the last slash. You may of course append it yourself to match your preferences.

Comment: Huh. Didn't even think of that. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname).

```
$ScriptDir = dirname($fullURL);
```